# Look for a defined sequence-pattern in XML

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, xquery, bpmn

I am thinking about how/if XQuery can be used to check whether a specific pattern exists in a XML file.

**Example**:
Think of a (simplified) XML representing a process flow (StartEvent > UserTask > AutoTask > EndEvent).

```
<process>
<startEvent id="start1">
    <outgoing>flow1</outgoing>
</startEvent>

<userTask id="user1">
    <incoming>flow1</incoming>
    <outgoing>flow2</outgoing>
</userTask>

<autoTask id="auto1">
    <incoming>flow2</incoming>
    <outgoing>flow3</outgoing>
</autoTask>

<endEvent id="end1">
    <incoming>flow3</incoming>
</endEvent>
<flow id="flow1" source="start1" target="user1"/>
<flow id="flow2" source="user1" target="auto1"/>
<flow id="flow3" source="auto1" target="end1"/>
</process>
```

Now I want to check whether somewhere in the file is an **element of type "userTask" which is immediately followed by an element of type "autoTask"**. Please note that this sequence needs to be checked by going along the incoming/outgoing flow definitions and cannot be derived from the ordering in the document.

Is there any way to do this with xquery/xpath?

Thanks in advance for your ideas!

Comment: I don't really get your flow concept. So how is your ordering defined in this example, i.e. how do flow1, flow2, flow3 interconnect? So flow1 starts at the element with id start1 due to the start attribute. But how does it determine where to go - Simply using @target (so a "flow" has just two points, start and end?). But if that would be the case, what information do incoming and outgoing elements actually deliver?!

Comment: @dirkk: specifying source/target in the flow elements and inside the tasks through incoming/outgoing elements certainly is duplication of information. However, this the structure that the BPMN specification mandates, so it is hardly the OP's fault.

Comment: @joergl I wasn't criticizing the OP, I honestly didn't (and still don't) understand the flow syntax here. I don't know this BPMN specification

Answer (score 1):

The following XPath 1.0 query lists all the flows whose source is a user task and target is an auto task:

```
//flow[@source=//userTask/@id and @target=//autoTask/@id]
```

Or, without descendants:

```
/process/flow[@source=/process/userTask/@id and @target=/process/autoTask/@id]
```

Or, as the information in the XML is redundant, you can ask the other way round.

```
//userTask[outgoing=//autoTask/incoming]
```

It lists all the user tasks whose outgoing flow is incoming for some auto task (again, you can replace `//` with `/process/`.

Comment: Thanks! I got the idea and was able to adapt it for solving my (real) problem.

Comment: @Christian: To express your gratitude just accept the answer.